# Optimum mapping between tesselated parallelograms and tesselated rectangles?

Tags: analytic-geometry, transformation

I have a lattice whose points are the vertices of many tessellated parallelograms. Each point is located at $\mathbf{x}=\alpha \mathbf a + \beta \mathbf b$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers and $\mathbf {a,b}$ are linearly independent. I would like to (bijectively) map this on to a rectangular lattice  $\mathbf{x}'=\lambda \mathbf x + \mu \mathbf y$, where $\lambda,\mu$ are again integers but $\mathbf{x,y}$ are not only linearly independent but also are orthogonal. Except that they are orthogonal, I have freedom to choose any $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ that I want. Each point should move as little as possible when moved from its place on the parallel lattice to its new place on the rectangular lattice. How can this be done?

Comment: The restrictions of your problem are not clear. If you choose very short basis  vectors $|\mathbf x|=|\mathbf y| = \varepsilon \ll |\mathbf a|, |\mathbf b|$, then all points will need to move not more than $\varepsilon$, which can be arbitrarily small

Comment: That's a good catch. I forgot to mention the requirement that the mapping between the two lattices be 1-1. If the basis vectors are made very small, too many unfilled points would open up on the rectangular lattice. (The question has been edited to reflect this.)

Comment: How about choosing $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ so that points along the longer diagonals remain fixed?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but I am not sure how to prove that it is optimal.